# Plugins for NetBeans 7.2 and some issues that I am facing

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-plugins, netbeans-7.2

I upgraded to NetBeans 7.2 from NetBeans 7.0 yesterday, and I don't see the "Java desktop application" option in NetBeans 7.2 unlike NetBeans 7.0. I googled and found out that it (the framework for Java desktop application) got dropped, and I also found out that there's a 'plugin' for it.

However, when I googled further to search for the plugin I found none. Is there such a plugin and does it work well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in *[Swing Application Framework Support - plugin detail](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/43836/swing-application-framework-support)*.

For a complete (and heated discussion), see *[NetBeans 7.1 Swing Application Support discontinued](http://forums.netbeans.org/viewtopic.php?t=43775)*.